# Jquery Duplication in mobile vs. of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a mobile version of my tables, I'm  using the following script to help do so:

```
<script>
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
    $('table#CustomerMainTable td').each(function () {
        var idx = $(this).index();
        $(this).prepend($('table#CustomerMainTable tr th').eq(idx).text());
        $('table#CustomerMainTable th').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

This works fine in my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2EJy3/1/

But in my app, it creates duplicates eg. The td would have the th printed twice, instead of once.  Does anyone know what would be causing this?

Comment: you know you can get the index by doing this: `.each(function (index) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Since it works in your fiddle, that implies a couple of things: 1) Your document structure is different in your app, or 2) your `ajaxSuccess` handler is being called twice. Turn on your debugger, or add some logging in your script before your `each()` call and see if the handler is being invoked twice.